# Binding nested arrays in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to bind a nested array to the SAPUI5 table. My JSON model:

```json
{
  "Departments": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "Name": "Транспортный цех 1",
      "Employees": [
        {
          "ID": "1000001234",
          "LastName": "Tom"
        },
        {
          "ID": "1000001234",
          "LastName": "Jerry",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "Name": "Транспортный цех 2",
      "Employees": [
        {
          "ID": "1000001234",
          "LastName": "Базенков"
        },
        {
          "ID": "1000001234",
          "LastName": "Базенков"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I am using SAPUI5 Table.

```xml
<Table items="{/Departments/Employees}">
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="LastName of Employee" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Input value="{LastName}" />
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

I am using above data binding to display last name to each one of the rows of the table. But it shows nothing.

Comment: You need a `sap.m.Tree`, `sap.ui.table.TreeTable`, or a combination of two list controls in order to display the data accordingly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478806/5846045

Answer (score 1):

As Jonas said in the comments, you would need to transform the data in the JSON model (and set it back into the model) if you wanted to create a table of all employees across all departments.

```js
const departments = jsonModel.getProperty("/Departments");
const allEmployees = departments.flatMap(department => department.Employees);
jsonModel.setProperty("/AllEmployees", allEmployees);
```

And in the binding, bind to `oDataItem>/AllEmployees`. See JSBin - https://jsbin.com/codonolive/1/edit?html,js,output

Alternatively, if you wanted just a specific department, you can bind the table to specific Department's employees by specifying the index of the array in the binding. I believe it should be `oDataItem>/Departments/0/Employees`.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (JSONModel) {

  // Read the view from the HTML page (this won't be needed productively)
  const view = sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent : jQuery("#main").html()
  });
  
  // Create the model
  const model = new JSONModel({
    "Departments": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Name": "Транспортный цех 1",
            "Employees": [
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Tom"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Jerry",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Name": "Транспортный цех 2",
            "Employees": [
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Базенков"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "1000001234",
                    "LastName": "Базенков"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]});
  
  // Change the binding of the table to '/AllEmployees' to use the code below:
  const allEmps = model.getProperty("/Departments").flatMap(dep => dep.Employees)
  model.setProperty("/AllEmployees", allEmps)
  
  // Configure the model
  view.setModel(model, "oDataItem")
  view.placeAt("content")
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script 
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3_dark" 
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" 
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
    
    
    <script id="main" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View
        displayBlock="true"
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns="sap.m">
      <Table 
          items="{oDataItem>/Departments/0/Employees}"                                       
          width="auto"
          fixedLayout="false" 
          mode="MultiSelect" >
          <columns>
              <Column width="auto">
                  <Text text="LastName of Employee" />
              </Column>
           </columns>
               <items>
                   <ColumnListItem>
                       <cells>
                            <Input editable="true" textAlign="Left" type="Text" change="onNameTextChange" width="15em" value="{path:'oDataItem>LastName'}" />
                       </cells>
                  </ColumnListItem>
               </items>           
       </Table>
     </mvc:View>
    </script>
    
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact">
    <div id='content'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `/Departments/Employees`

Which list of `Employees` should the table pick from the `Departments` list? The table cannot know.

The users, however, know which employees from which departments they want to see. Let **them** decide by allowing them to pick a department first, and then you can bind the corresponding employee list to the table.

I.e. either a tree-like control or a set of two list controls (one for departments, one for the employee list) is needed in your case. Here is an example: https://embed.plnkr.co/fVCzodmvWzieh2LH